# How does django-rest-framework decide what the default `allowed_methods` should be for a `ModelViewSet`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The company I work for has 2 projects that use django and DRF 3.

- both projects have a ViewSet that extends `ModelViewSet`
- both ViewSets do not explicitly define the `allowed_methods` property and are just using whatever DRF figures should be the default
- both ViewSets do not override or define any handler methods (`create()`, `update()`, `partial_update()`, `patch()`, etc.)

However, in one project the `allowed_methods` property defaults to `[u'GET', u'PUT', u'PATCH', u'DELETE', u'HEAD', u'OPTIONS']`.  For the other `allowed_methods` defaults to `[u'GET', u'POST', u'HEAD', u'OPTIONS']`.  Consequently, I get a 405 response with

> Method "PATCH" not allowed.

when I attempt to send a PATCH request.

What causes project 2 to be more restricted?

Answer (score 3):

DRF [only exposes](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/6284bceaaff0e53349131164ce5c16cda8deb715/rest_framework/views.py#L139) Django's internal `_allowed_methods()` so we should review the implementation of [that method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/16411b8400ad08f90c236bb2e18f65c655f903f8/django/views/generic/base.py#L108):

```
def _allowed_methods(self):
    return [m.upper() for m in self.http_method_names if hasattr(self, m)]
```

where `self.http_method_names` is defined as:

```
http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']
```

Is there a difference in what methods these clases define that could explain what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The only methods the 2 ViewSets define are `get_queryset()` and `get_serializer_class()`, so I'm not seeing anything there that could explain the difference... I did notice that in project 1 the `patch()` method is directly mapped to `partial_update()` (the one defined in `ModelViewSet`), so `hasattr(self, 'patch')` returns true, whereas in project 2 there is no connection there.  Any idea what would cause that in project 1?  The ViewSet, itself, is not making/defining that connection...

Answer (score 3):

**The short answer:**

In my case, I was accidentally sending my `PATCH` to the `list` URL, rather than the `put/patch` URL.

**The longer answer:**

I found that the problem isn't that one project has different defaults for `allowed_methods`, it's that the `action_map` and `allowed_methods` properties of the ViewSet change based on which of the ViewSet URLs you hit, since the `action_map` is influenced by the router (see `SimpleRouter.routes`).

So if you try to hit "//[base_url]/your-model/" with `PATCH` or `PUT`, as I was doing, it will say that only `['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']` are allowed, and `patch()` will NOT be linked to `partial_update()`, even though it uses the same ViewSet class and `partial_update()` is present in that class.

If you want to send a `PATCH`, you have to send it to "//[base_url]/your-model/[some_id]/".

Comment: This was a very helpful explanation