# Even if I send various methods to my django api server by postman, my django api server always receives them only as get

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Even if I send it with a method other than get, my django api server always receives it as get. What's wrong with this?

```
class A(APIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

        def get(self, request):
                return JsonResponse({"message": "Hello, world!"})
```

Comment: See also: [How does django-rest-framework decide what the default `allowed_methods` should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36142589/530160)

Comment: I think your question is not clear, please change it

Comment: I tested it with Postman, and it was not an apiview problem. It's strange that my django api server always gets it as a get.

Comment: @ppsgg Can you show an example request with the issue? How do you know the application is receiving all methods as GET? Show your urls.py too

Comment: Everyone thnaks..I solved this problem. am..that's problem is my aws server http to https redirect. aws https redirect translate all request method to get...

Answer (score 0):

As you can test from Postman (if you have it), you cannot use POST, so there's no need to disable something. It's already only for GET requests.

Comment: I tested Postman now, but my django receive anything to get method, Is there any wrong setting?

Comment: What if your question again? Is it that you want to use basic auth or something like that?

Comment: Even if I send various methods to my django api server by postman, my django api server always receives them only as get.
Postman is not broken. I also tested it with curl, and the same symptoms appeared.
I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Everyone thnaks..I solved this problem. am..that's problem is my aws server http to https redirect. aws https redirect translate all request method to get...

Answer (score 0):

You should add "/" at the end of the postman url.
For example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup/